# Adding new page to Front end

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, frontend, catalogsearch, product-view

**UPDATED**

I am trying to add new page on front end. I am doing as following. I have a form, where I am using my action to load the view. On button click it never goes to controller, please help me, what I am doing wrong.

My form is as

```
<div id="abc-category-search">
    <form id="abc-category-search-form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('helloworld') ?>">
        <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search by product SKU/Category') ?>:</label>
        <input id="abc-category-search-string" name="search" value="" />
        <input id="abc-category-search-cat" type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" />
        <button id="abc-category-search-submit" type="submit" class="engine-btn" value="" >
            <?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And I am adding page  like this.

```
app/code/local/Abc/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <Abc_Helloworld>
                <version>
                    0.1.0
                </version>
            </Abc_Helloworld>
        </modules>
        <blocks>
            <abc_helloworld>
                <class>Abc_Helloworld_Block</class>
            </abc_helloworld>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Abc_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>abc_helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>

    </frontend>
</config>
```

And

```
app/code/local/Abc/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

<?php

class Abc_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

And

```
    app/code/local/Abc/Helloworld/Block/Helloworld.php
<?php

    class Abc_HelloWorld_Block_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
        // necessary methods
    }
```

And Layout file is

```
 app/design/frontend/default/Jin/layout/abc_helloworld.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <helloworld_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="abc_helloworld/helloWorld" name="helloworld_any_block" template="helloworld/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```

And .phtml

```
app/design/frontend/default/jin/template/helloworld/helloworld.phtml

<div>
    <?php
        echo 'Abdul Ghaffar'; 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rajeev I have added the module as you said, now it is working, going to controller and loading my view (if I put my new module's url i.e http://myweb.com/helloworld in url bar), but there is  a problem, as you can see in **Form** I have an action, pointing to my controller, on clicking submit button it go to controller, but url never changes(new  Mage::getUrl('helloworld')) is never loaded, can you point me, what could be reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem resides in your layout update xml file, particularly in the following block declaration.

```
<block type="abc_helloworld/index" name="helloworld_any_block" template="helloworld/index.phtml" />
```

Magento fails to find this block, because you don't have block declaration in your `config.xml` file. So you need to update your config.xml file with following code:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <abc_helloworld>
                <class>Abc_HelloWorld_Block</class>
            </abc_helloworld>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here you are declaring your block group name. That's it.

If you want to use your own custom block, then the reference to your block will also need to change like this.

```
<block type="abc_helloworld/helloWorld" name="helloworld_any_block" template="helloworld/index.phtml" />
```

Difference here is, I am using `abc_helloworld/helloWorld` instead of `abc_helloworld/index`. This is because your block type reference looks for a block `Abc_HelloWorld_Block_Index` and which is not defined.

Also make sure `default/jin` is your current package theme. Otherwise it would be better to move your phtml template file to `base/default` package theme directory since it is the final fallback location for Magento.

Make sure you clear all cache after all these changes made. Happy coding

### EDIT - 1

Your form action is also need to be changed.

It should be like

```
<form id="abc-category-search-form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('helloworld') ?>">
```

Let Magento generate correct URL for you. :)

### EDIT - 2

Use below `config.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Abc_HelloWorld>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Abc_HelloWorld>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <abc_helloworld>
                    <class>Abc_HelloWorld_Block</class>
                </abc_helloworld>
            </blocks>
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <helloworld>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Abc_HelloWorld</module>
                        <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                    </args>
                </helloworld>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <helloworld>
                        <file>abc_helloworld.xml</file>
                    </helloworld>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

Main difference here is, you use `Helloworld` instead of `HelloWorld` in almost all configuration and I also changed router frontname to `helloworld` instead of `Helloworld`.

Make sure you have activation file for you module

File : `app\etc\modules\Abc_HelloWorld.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_HelloWorld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Abc_HelloWorld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

### FINAL EDIT

Magento is Letter sensitive. Both me and digitalPianism says samething. You are using the file structure `Abc\HelloWorld`. Hence you need to use same naming concept. ie `Abc_HelloWorld`. Or if you like to have a class name `Abc_Helloworld`, then your file structure should be `Abc/Helloworld`.

Now about layout update xml file. You have a template file `helloworld/helloworld.phtml` and hence you need to specify it correctly in your block. ie

```
<block type="abc_helloworld/helloWorld" name="helloworld_any_block" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml" />
```

This block will generally say 3 things to Magento.

Assumes your module is `Abc_HelloWorld` and not `Abc_Helloworld` and your file structure is like `Abc/HelloWorld`

1. My block is of type = `abc_helloworld/helloWorld`. This will be read by Magento like `Abc_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld`.
2. My block name is `helloworld_any_block`
3. Use `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template\helloworld/helloworld.phtml` as my block's template.

Comment: I have followed you, but no success

Comment: please update your qn with updated files and let me know

Comment: you also need to update layout section in config.xml as digital pianism indicated.

Comment: I have updated the post, please have a look on it. (can you refer me to some other page)

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar see my edit-2

Comment: Done with it, now it is coming in controller, but not loading view(.phtml)

Comment: `<block type="abc_helloworld/index" name="helloworld_any_block" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml" />` use this block. If this is not worked, then move your `abc_helloworld.xml` and `helloworld.phtml` file to `base/default` package theme directory

Comment: In your answer you have suggested me to use <block type="abc_helloworld/helloWorld" ........ insted of <block type="abc_helloworld/index" , now you are saying to use it again,

Comment: oh sorry. this is the right block . `<block type="abc_helloworld/helloWorld" name="helloworld_any_block" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml" />` . This time you are going to make it :)

Comment: It didn't work, also moved to  "base/default"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41390/discussion-between-abdul-ghaffar-and-rajeev-k-tomy).

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is that your form is not calling the right action.

The front name you declare in your `config.xml` is the following: `Helloworld` (by the way, I suggest you change it to `helloworld` ).

So your form action should be `helloworld/index/index` instead of `abc_helloWorld/index/index`

On top of that your frontend layout declaration is missing the filename type.

Instead of:

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
                <file>abc_helloworld</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

It should be:

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
                <file>abc_helloworld.xml</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Finally, your blocks are not declared at all. You should the following under the `<config>` tag of your `config.xml` :

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <abc_helloworld>
            <class>Abc_Helloworld_Block</class>
        </abc_helloworld>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Last point, I reckon you have a problem with your module folder.

Indeed, the module name is declared in your `config.xml` as `Abc_Helloworld` but your folder are declared as:

```
app/code/local/Abc/HelloWorld
```

You should change it to:

```
app/code/local/Abc/Helloworld
```

And change your classes accordingly.

Comment: Same result, nothing is changed

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar see my update

Comment: I have followed you, but no success

Comment: I have updated the post, please have a look on it. (can you refer me to some other page)

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar see my update. Also try to change `<frontName>Helloworld</frontName>` to `<frontName>helloworld</frontName>`

Comment: What is difference in 'app/code/local/Abc/HelloWorld' and 'app/code/local/Abc/HelloWorld'

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar the 'W' is lowercase so it becomes 'w'

Comment: got it, it is "w" not "W"

Comment: Done with it, now it is coming in controller, but not loading view(.phtml)

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar rename `app/design/frontend/default/jin/template/helloworld/helloworld.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/default/jin/template/helloworld/index.phtml`

Comment: That's my bad :)

Comment: Same result, no view