# Form Submission not loading correct url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, frontend, forms, action

**UPDATED-3**

I have added a new page to front end, as you can see [Adding new page to Front end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121772/adding-new-page-to-front-end/121779#121779), by fixing some issues, it is working now. but the issue I am facing now is in my from

```
    <div id="abc-category-search">
    <!--action="http://stage.oliver-marketing.com/homesearch">-->
    <!--method="post" action="<?php //echo Mage::getUrl('helloworld/index/index') ?>"--> 
    <form id="abc-category-search-form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('homesearch/index/index') ?>">
        <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search by product SKU/Category') ?>:</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"/>
        <input id="abc-category-search-string" name="search" value="" />
        <input id="abc-category-search-cat" type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" />
        <button id="abc-category-search-submit" type="submit" class="engine-btn" value="" >
            <?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="ajax-loader" class="hide" style="">
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Searching please wait...'); ?></p>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ajax_loader_green_64.gif'); ?>" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $("#abc-category-search-form input").keypress(function (e) {
            if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
                $('#abc-category-search-submit').trigger('click');
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
        // Attach a submit handler to the form
        $("#abc-category-search-form").submit(function (event) {
            // Stop form from submitting normally
            event.preventDefault();
            // Get some values from elements on the page:
            var $form = $(this),
                    term = $form.find("input[name='search']").val(),
                    cat = $form.find("input[name='category']").val(),
                    url = $form.attr("action");
            // Send the data using post
            var posting = $.post(url, {search: term, category: cat});
            $("#ajax-loader").show();
            // Put the results in a div
            posting.done(function (data) {
                $("#ajax-loader").hide();
                $("#abc-category-search-string").val('');
            });
        });
    });
    jQuery(document).load(function ($) {
        $("div.hero-top-content h2").html("Some Text Here")
    });
</script>
```

my action `action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('helloworld')` gives me url to my new page, **myweb.com/helloworld**, but issue is that on clicking submit button on my form, it go to related controller and tried to load accurate view(my custom page),but url never changes,ideally it should be changed.  if I use  **myweb.com/helloworld** in search bar manually, it loads correct page, don't where I am doing some thing wrong
my controller is

```
app/code/local/Abc/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

<?php

class Abc_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

And my `config.xml` looks like this.

```
app/code/local/Abc/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <Abc_Helloworld>
                <version>
                    0.1.0
                </version>
            </Abc_Helloworld>
        </modules>
        <blocks>
            <abc_helloworld>
                <class>Abc_Helloworld_Block</class>
            </abc_helloworld>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Abc_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>abc_helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>

    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: you can use action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('myweb/helloworld')

Comment: @Rakesh please see my updated post,

Comment: in which Action of Controller  are you want to submit form?

Comment: @AmitBera please have look on update

Comment: I have just one  Action in my Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depend on what is your `<frontName>modulename</frontName>`

try that with complete url

```
method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('helloworld/index/index') ?>"
```

you are using `event.preventDefault();` that are stop form from submitting.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: which url it is taking too?

Comment: I have update my post

Comment: As you asked, currently it is on Home page http://myweb.com/, after action it it should be changed to http://myweb.com/helloworld

Comment: did you check your ajax url is working in console what error is showing in console?

Comment: you are using `event.preventDefault();` that are stop form from submiting.

Comment: I am using event.preventDefault();,   add some other data before submission, if I remove event.preventDefault() it work, now have to figure an other way to pass data....thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your module url work like

**routename/controllername/actionname**

In your case route is **helloworld**

Controllername is IndexController so name is **index**

Action name of IndexController.php file where you need to send your form data we considering indexAction name is **index**

As per url

**routename/controllername/actionname**

In your case url will be

**helloworld/index/index**

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Your url is `<?php echo Mage::getUrl('helloworld/index/index') ?>`